# Matrix of an affine transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, affine-geometry

> Let $p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3$ the vertices of a tetrahedron in $R^3$ and $f$
>   the  affine transformation such that $$f(p_0)=p_1 \hspace{3ex}
>  f(p_1)=p_2 \hspace{3ex} f(p_2)=p_3 \hspace{3ex} f(p_3)=p_0$$
>
> Find the matrix of $f$ with $p_0 $ as origin and
>   $B=\{\overline{p_0p_1},\hspace{2ex}\overline{p_1p_2},\hspace{2ex}\overline{p_2p_3}\}$
>   as basis.

My work

$\vec{f}(\overline{p_0p_1})=\overline{f(p_0)f(p_1)}=\overline{p_1p_2}$

$\vec{f}(\overline{p_1p_2})=\overline{f(p_1)f(p_2)}=\overline{p_2p_3}$

$\vec{f}(\overline{p_2p_3})=\overline{f(p_3)f(p_0)}=\overline{p_3p_0}=-\overline{p_0p_3}=-(\overline{p_0p_1}+\overline{p_1p_2}+\overline{p_2p_3})$

Then 
$$M_{B,B}(\vec{f})=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&-1\\
1&0&-1\\
0&1&-1\\
\end{array}\right) $$

So the matrix is 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0\\
?&0&0&-1\\
?&1&0&-1\\
?&0&1&-1\\
\end{array}\right) $$

Question: Is my work correct? How can I find the $f(p_0) $coordinates?

Comment: Each column is the image of a basis vector. You’re given that $f(p_0)=p_1$ and $\overline{p_0p_1}=p_1-p_0$, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> $\vec{f}(\overline{p_2p_3})=\overline{f(p_3)f(p_0)}=\overline{p_3p_0}=-\overline{p_0p_3}=-(\overline{p_0p_1}+\overline{p_1p_2}+\overline{p_2p_3})$

but this is mistaken; I think it should be

$\vec{f}(\overline{p_2p_3})=\overline{f(p_\color{red}2)f(p_\color{red}3)}=\overline{p_3p_0}=-\overline{p_0p_3}=-(\overline{p_0p_1}+\overline{p_1p_2}+\overline{p_2p_3})$

---

You ask "how do I find the $f(p_0)$ coordinates?"

I'm not sure exactly how your text/teacher is expressing affine xforms as matrices, so I don't know how to fill in the first column, but you do know that $f(p_0) = p_1$, so you can write 
$$
f(p_0) = p_1 = p_0 + (p_1 - p_0) = p_0 + b_1
$$
where $b_1$ is the first element of your basis. That makes me suspect that your matrix should be something like 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0\\
\color{red}1&0&0&-1\\
\color{red}0&1&0&-1\\
\color{red}0&0&1&-1\\
\end{array}\right)
$$